# Add an integer right after the integer which is bigger than the one added. Then move every element after the newly added 1 position to the right

Tags: arrays, c

Example:
Enter a number:5 (User input)
Array Before:6,4,3,2,1
Array After:6,5,4,3,2,1
Find the first integer which is bigger than the user input (6>5), put the input number and move every element after it with one position. Please explain the logic behind the solution if you have one as I am a student as of now and need help with visualizing it. The array is made big enough to store all six numbers! This is where I struggle:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(*pNumAdd<array1[i])
        {
            array1[i+1]=*pNumAdd;
            for(j=i;j<size;j++)
            {
                array1[j+1]=array1[j];
            }
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better first move them and then add (insert) the number.

Comment: Further, you need to move the highest first, then the one before it, etc. Otherwise you overwrite  them,

Comment: What if the before array is `[6, 4, 3]` and user input = 2. Would your after array be = `[6, 2, 4, 3]`?

Answer (score 0):

The way you shift the elements, you end up overwriting all the elements of before array with the element at index `i` which was the first element greater than user input.

You can instead shift the elements from the back of `array1` like shown below.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if(*pNumAdd<array1[i])
    {
        for(j=size-1;j>i;j--)
        {
            array1[j+1]=array1[j];
        }
        array1[i+1]=*pNumAdd;
        break;
    }
}
```